# Docker Elasticsearch uncaught exception in thread, failed to bind service, Format version is not supported

Tags: java, docker, elasticsearch

This is MacOS 11.6, Docker 20.10.8, docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.10.1

The process ends with uncaught exception in thread, failed to bind service, Format version is not supported.

```
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2021-10-14T22:34:19,526Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "c5bf38c408e2", "message": "loaded module [x-pack-stack]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2021-10-14T22:34:19,527Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "c5bf38c408e2", "message": "loaded module [x-pack-voting-only-node]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2021-10-14T22:34:19,528Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "c5bf38c408e2", "message": "loaded module [x-pack-watcher]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2021-10-14T22:34:19,529Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "c5bf38c408e2", "message": "no plugins loaded" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2021-10-14T22:34:19,627Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.e.NodeEnvironment", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "c5bf38c408e2", "message": "using [1] data paths, mounts [[/usr/share/elasticsearch/data (/dev/vda1)]], net usable_space [46gb], net total_space [58.4gb], types [ext4]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2021-10-14T22:34:19,628Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.e.NodeEnvironment", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "c5bf38c408e2", "message": "heap size [2.4gb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]" }
uncaught exception in thread [main]
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2021-10-14T22:34:20,071Z", "level": "ERROR", "component": "o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "c5bf38c408e2", "message": "uncaught exception in thread [main]",
"stacktrace": ["org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException: ElasticsearchException[failed to bind service]; nested: IndexFormatTooNewException[Format version is not supported (resource SimpleFSIndexInput(path=\"/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes/0/_state/_90.cfs\") [slice=_90.fdt]): 4 (needs to be between 1 and 3)];",
"at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:174) ~[elasticsearch-7.10.1.jar:7.10.1]",
"at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:161) ~[elasticsearch-7.10.1.jar:7.10.1]",
"at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:86) ~[elasticsearch-7.10.1.jar:7.10.1]",
"at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:127) ~[elasticsearch-cli-7.10.1.jar:7.10.1]",
"at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90) ~[elasticsearch-cli-7.10.1.jar:7.10.1]",
"at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:126) ~[elasticsearch-7.10.1.jar:7.10.1]",
"at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:92) ~[elasticsearch-7.10.1.jar:7.10.1]",
"Caused by: org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: failed to bind service",
"at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:729) ~[elasticsearch-7.10.1.jar:7.10.1]",
"at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:289) ~[elasticsearch-7.10.1.jar:7.10.1]",
"at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.<init>(Bootstrap.java:227) ~[elasticsearch-7.10.1.jar:7.10.1]",
"at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:227) ~[elasticsearch-7.10.1.jar:7.10.1]",
"at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:393) ~[elasticsearch-7.10.1.jar:7.10.1]",
"at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:170) ~[elasticsearch-7.10.1.jar:7.10.1]",
"... 6 more",
```

*docker-compose.yml*

```yaml
version:  '3.9'

services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.10.1
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 1536M
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - "http.cors.enabled=true"
      - "http.cors.allow-origin=http://localhost:8090"
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1536m -Xmx1536m"
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
    volumes:
      - elasticsearch:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "curl --silent --fail localhost:9200/_cluster/health || exit 1" ]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 5
```

Comment: It sounds like it is getting tripped up by an existing file in a newer version...  How are you running the image, are you using an existing volume or bind mount?

Comment: No external mounts. Only a volume is defined in the docker-compose.yml file.

Comment: I added the ``docker-compose.yml`` to the post.

Comment: Looked at the files in the volume. Only one is big-endian, a DB file. The binaries are x86-64 to match the CPU in the Mac, Intel. This looks like it could be normal.
``/usr/share/elasticsearch/modules/ingest-geoip/GeoLite2-ASN.mmdb: a.out big-endian 32-bit demand paged executable not stripped``

Comment: Thanks for the clue @NicolasGaller, it seems to have solved it by changing the volume and the healthcheck.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve the problem by changing the volume path and the healthcheck in the YML.

*docker-compose.yml*

```
volumes:
  - ./esdata:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
healthcheck:
  test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "curl --silent --fail localhost:9200/_cat/nodes?v\\&pretty || exit 1" ]
```